# ViewPager alpha animation when returning to the first element

Tags: android, animation, android-viewpager

the question is: there is a ViewPager with the same type of fragments. There is a Spinner with a list of values that, when selected, replace the content of all fragments and move to 1 fragment. Is it possible to add the alpha animation of the ViewPager at the moment of selecting a value from the list and then the first fragment will be selected? Tried to do this way, but the animation is always called up clumsily and it happens that it appears several times.

**ActivityViewPager**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActivityCompat.postponeEnterTransition(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_treining_info);
    if (getIntent().hasExtra(ClassTraining.KEY_TR_TYPE)) {
        type = getIntent().getIntExtra(ClassTr.KEY_TR_TYPE, 1);
        lvl = getIntent().getIntExtra(ClassTr.KEY_TR_LVL, 1);
    }
    animation = new AnimationClass(this);
    dataRes=DataResCompound.getInstance();
    clInfo = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.cl_info);
    initPagerAdapter();
    initSpinner();
}

private void initPagerAdapter() {
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        lvl = position+1;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
          int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

      @Override
      public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
      }
    });
    pager.setCurrentItem(lvl-1);
}



private void initSpinner() {
    final int[] size1 = {0};
    //ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.trainings, R.layout.spiner_layout);
    spnTrain = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spn_train);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.trainings, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spnTrain.setAdapter(adapter);
    spnTrain.setSelection(type-1);
    spnTrain.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(isStart>0) {
                lvl = 1;
                type=position+1;
                getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().clear();
                pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                alphaViewTraining();
            }
            isStart++;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
}

private void alphaViewTraining(){
    clInfo.startAnimation(animation.getAlphaAnimation(pager, clInfo, 2, lvl-1));  } private class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return FragmentPageTrainInfo.newInstance(typeTrening, position+1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        int lvl=position+1;
        return "Уровень " + lvl;
    }
}
```

**AnimationClass**

```
public Animation getAlphaAnimation(View _view, final View layout, final int typeView, Object _value){
view=_view;
value=_value;

in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,  R.anim.alpha_in);
out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.alpha_out);

out.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        setValueToView(view, layout, value, typeView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});
return out;}private void setValueToView(View view, View layout, Object value, int typeView){
((ViewPager)view).setCurrentItem((int)value);
layout.startAnimation(in);
break;
view.startAnimation(in);}
```

It seems to me that it's a matter of overlapping the standard animation ViewPager and mine. Whether prompt it is possible to make something?